# CMake: *.hpp and *.cpp in target_include_*

Tags: c++, cmake

Here is an MWE that isolates a problem I have in a larger project.
(I am still wrapping my head around `CMake`.)
Here is the layout of the project:
[image]

Inside `tests/CMakeLists.txt` we have

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

add_executable(test_class_a test_class_a.cpp)
target_include_directories(test_class_a PUBLIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/modules/class_a/)
```

Now, when I try to compile `test_class_a`, it complains with something like 
[image]
Essentially, although inside `test_class_a.cpp` file I have included `#include "class_a.hpp"` and it looks fine there, somehow `class_a.cpp` does not get invited into the party, it seems.
How I make sure it does, without having to add `#include "class_a.cpp"`, which would be ugly?

Inside the top-most `CMakeLists.txt` I have of course `add_subdirectory(modules/tests/)`.

EDIT: the comment below says I need to add it inside `add_executables`, and it does fix the problem. However, this can be my misconception, but shouldn't it be the case that `class_a.hpp` and `class_a.cpp` are somehow semantically "linked" together, without me having to include the *.cpp inside the sources explicitly? Sorry for a long question, you are certainly free to delete it.

EDIT:
Based on the accepted answer below, I've settled on the following `CMakeLists.txt`, which from now on will likely be my *modus operandi* in `CMake`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

add_library(class_a ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/modules/class_a/class_a.cpp)
add_executable(test_class_a test_class_a.cpp)
target_include_directories(test_class_a PUBLIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/modules/class_a/)
target_link_libraries(test_class_a PUBLIC class_a)
```

Comment: *"but shouldn't it be the case that class_a.hpp and class_a.cpp are somehow semantically "linked" together"* - no, from the perspective of compiler or linker they are unrelated. Also note that `include_directories` has no impact on linker.

Comment: *"you are certainly free to delete it"* - questions should not be deleted, they should be improved and answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First solution: add `class_a.cpp` into `add_executable`:

```
add_executable(test_class_a test_class_a.cpp modules/class_a/class_a.cpp)
```

Second solution: create a library:

```
add_library(class_a modules/class_a/class_a.cpp)
target_include_directories(class_a PUBLIC modules/class_a/)
target_link_libraries(test_class_a PUBLIC class_a)
```

Probably, you already have a library: `modules/class_a/CMakeLists.txt` is there. Then you can do:

```
add_subdirectory(modules/class_a)
target_link_libraries(test_class_a PUBLIC <library name>)
```

(Paths should be fixed appropriately.)

> However, this can be my misconception, but shouldn't it be the case that class_a.hpp and class_a.cpp are somehow semantically "linked" together, without me having to include the *.cpp inside the sources explicitly?

How should CMake know that? These files are completely unrelated from the point of view of CMake. It's your job to tell it they actually are related.